# Android Studio 3.1 - Exception in plugin Android Support.Ocurred 2 times since the last clear.Unread. Disable Plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I'm new to Android Studio. I created a project and put an activity with the Navigation Drawer to later modify it to my liking, a package called menu was created automatically and within it **activity_main_drawer.xml** and **main.xml**. 
However, when I try to open the activity_main_drawer.xml on the Design tab, fatal IDE errors appear.

Here's the error:
[image: error]

This is what happens when I open the **activity_main_drawer.xml** file:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all it shows to report google because menu item not render a design in design tab for your menu items**

Your `activity_main_drawer.xml` code shuld be like this and move your `activity_main_drawer.xml` in layout resource directory, not in menu item

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and this is for menu item you named with `main.xml`, change it as per your requirement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_one"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_drafts_black_24dp"
              android:title="Item 1" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_two"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_drafts_black_24dp"
              android:title="Item 2" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_three"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_drafts_black_24dp"
              android:title="Item 3" />
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/group_menu">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_four"
              android:title="Item 4" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_five"
              android:title="Item 5" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Title 1">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_six"
                  android:icon="@drawable/ic_drafts_black_24dp"
                  android:title="Item 6" />
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_seven"
                  android:icon="@drawable/ic_drafts_black_24dp"
                  android:title="Item 7" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```